# I changed some of the colors of my video but now I can't revert them back to the original

Tags: color, color-management

I changed the saturation of the colors in my video clips. I rendered the video, then I decided I didn't like the colors. But now I can't change the colors back to how they are originally. Trying to set saturation back to 1.00 and right clicking and also clicking on 'reset to default value' but it isn't changing back.

I am also working with a proxy. The video is quite long and there are alot of edits I don't feel like doing again if I started a whole new project again.

Comment: Post some screenshots of what you are doing, please and describe how exactly you are doing it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vCJgll5

I click on the video strip, and change the saturation under filters